# Fill the array using matrix in each loop in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, dimension

I have multiple files containing the data in tabulated form. I want to generate a 3-dimensional array in which the data from each file stored in the third dimension. For example, if I have 10 files then data from the first file will store in the first layer of 3D array, data from the second file in the second layer and so on.

Here is the dummy code I am using but it does not work correctly.

```
# reading data from the file ( I have a list of files names as fname)
dataDum <- read.table(fname[i],header = F, sep =';', skip=121, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Assigning data to the array. I have already generated an empty array with the desired dimension
finaldata[, , i]=dataDum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear "why" your code is not working properly, as there is not reproducible example. As it is it should work correctly given the inputs are as expected. For example:

```
arr <- array(data = 0, dim = c(10,10,3));
for(i in 1:3){
    mat <- matrix(rnorm(10^2), ncol = 10);
    arr[,,i] <- mat
}
arr
```

If an error occurs it is likely due to `dataDum` being a `data.frame`. Explicitly using `as.matrix(dataDum)` would fix such an issue.

Comment: No problem, i hope it was useful and allowed you to fix your problem. I suggest upvoting and/or marking the question as answered (button near the upvote or any answers upvote button). This helps making the question more visible for others with similar questions, and incentivizes me and others to answer your questions in the future. :-)